# How to retrieve data properly using realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, uicollectionview, realm

I had a problem to retrieve data using realm. What i wanna do is caching the data so that i can use it when user first load the app or user does not have internet connection. Below is the logic what i wanna do.

*request from fb api -> fb return 10 data -> display returned data and cache returned data -> if user doesn't have internet connection display cache data or if user have internet connection fetch new data.*

below is my code :

**FBVideo.h**

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface FBVideo : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pageBefore;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pageAfter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thumbnailsURI;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *titleDescription;
@property NSString *id;

@end
```

**FBVideo.m**

```
#import "FBVideo.h"

@implementation FBVideo

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}

// Specify default values for properties
+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
    return @{@"pageBefore":@"", @"pageAfter":@"", @"thumbnailsURI":@"", @"titleDescription":@""};
}

+ (NSArray *)ignoredProperties {
    return @[];
}

@end
```

**PageVideosCVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "FBVideo.h"

@interface PageVideosCVC : UICollectionViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *videoArray;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *pageID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *pageName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *playerController;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CATransform3D initialTransformation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *shownIndexes;

//@property (strong, nonatomic) FBVideo *fbVideoRealm;

@end
```

**PageVideosCVC.m**

```
#import "PageVideosCVC.h"
#import "facebook.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]


@interface PageVideosCVC () <UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate> {
    NSString *pageBefore;
    NSString *pageAfter;
    NSString *thumbnailsURI;
    Reachability *internetReachable;
    NSDictionary *videoInfoToSaveInRealm;

   // RLMResults *videoResultsFrom
}
@end

@implementation PageVideosCVC
@synthesize videoArray;

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

    videoArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    /* Make a card effect, rotate the angle of the collectionviewcell to -15

     1) Start with an identity transform, which is a fancy math term for “do nothing.”
     2) Call CATransform3DRotate to apply a rotation of -15 degrees (in radians), where the negative value indicates a clockwise rotation.
     3) Apply the rotation around the axis 0.0, 0.0, 1.0; this represents the z-axis, where x=0, y=0, and z=1.
     4) Applying just the rotation to the card isn’t enough, as this simply rotates the card about its center. To make it look like it’s tipped over on a corner, add a translation or shift where the negative values indicate a shift up and to the left.

     */
    CGFloat rotationAngleDegrees = -15;
    CGFloat rotationAngleRadians = rotationAngleDegrees * (M_PI/180);
    CGPoint offsetPositioning = CGPointMake(-20, -20);

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationAngleRadians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offsetPositioning.x, offsetPositioning.y, 0.0);
    _initialTransformation = transform;

    _shownIndexes = [NSMutableSet set];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    navBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x266593);



    // Altering the font style of the navigation bar title
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    [self.view addSubview: navBar];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Down Arrow.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:)];

//        UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
//                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
//                                                                      target:self
//                                                                      action:@selector(backButtonTapped:)];
    [cancelItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    //    UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
    //                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
    //                                                                target:self action:nil];


    NSString *selectedPageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", self.pageName];

    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:selectedPageName];
    //   navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem;
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelItem;
    navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navItem,nil];

    [UIBarButtonItem appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [self loadVideo:@"a" pagesID:self.pageID];

}


#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([pageBefore isEqual:pageBefore]) {
     return videoArray.count;
    }

    return videoArray.count + 1;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == [videoArray count] - 1) {
        NSLog(@"page after : %@", pageAfter);
        [self loadVideo:pageAfter pagesID:self.pageID];
    }

    if (![self.shownIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.shownIndexes addObject:indexPath];

        // Transform collectionviewcell layer
        UIView *card = [(UICollectionViewCell*)cell contentView];

        card.layer.transform = self.initialTransformation;
        card.layer.opacity = 0.5;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            card.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
            card.layer.opacity = 1;
        }];
    }



}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

        if (indexPath.row == [videoArray count]) {
            NSLog(@"this is last cell, later make it UIActivityIndicatorView");
        } else {

//            RLMResults *objects;
//            
//            objects = [FBVideo allObjects];
//            FBVideo *fbVideoRealm = objects[indexPath.row];
//            
//            UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
//            NSURL *thumbnailImage = [NSURL URLWithString:fbVideoRealm.thumbnailsURI];
//            [imgView sd_setImageWithURL:thumbnailImage placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
//            
//            UILabel *titleDescription = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
//            titleDescription.text = fbVideoRealm.titleDescription;

            NSDictionary *videoData = weakSelf.videoArray[indexPath.row];
            NSDictionary *videoThumbnails = [videoData valueForKey:@"thumbnails"];
            NSArray *thumbnailsData = [videoThumbnails objectForKey:@"data"][0];
            thumbnailsURI = [thumbnailsData valueForKey:@"uri"];

            UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
            NSURL *thumbnailImage = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailsURI];
            [imgView sd_setImageWithURL:thumbnailImage placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];

            UILabel *titleDescription = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
            titleDescription.text = videoData[@"description"];

        }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *videoSource = videoArray[indexPath.row];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[videoSource valueForKey:@"source"]];

    self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    [[self.playerController view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]]; // Frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview:[self.playerController view]];
    self.playerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    self.playerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    [self.playerController play];

    // Play the video using AVPlayer iOS9 above
//    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
//    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
//    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
//    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
//    [player play];

}

- (void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    NSNumber *reason = [aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];

    if ([reason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        // Your done button action here
        // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"done button tapped");

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                                      object:nil];
        [self.playerController stop];
        [self.playerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


- (IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

- (void)loadVideo:(NSString*)currentPage pagesID:(NSString*)pagesID{

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    NSString *fbToken = [facebook currentFBAccessToken];
    NSString *fbNextVideoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/%@/videos?access_token=%@&pretty=0&fields=source,description,thumbnails.limit(1),length&limit=10&after=%@", pagesID, fbToken, currentPage];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager GET:fbNextVideoURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *videoDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject];

        if (responseObject != nil) {

            [weakSelf.videoArray addObjectsFromArray:[videoDict valueForKeyPath:@"data"]];

            pageBefore = [videoDict valueForKeyPath:@"paging.cursors.before"];
            pageAfter = [videoDict valueForKeyPath:@"paging.cursors.after"];

            // Caching pageBefore, pageAfter, thumbnailsURI, titleDescription data to REALM

            for (videoInfoToSaveInRealm in weakSelf.videoArray) {
                NSDictionary *videoThumbnails = [videoInfoToSaveInRealm valueForKey:@"thumbnails"];
                NSArray *thumbnailsData = [videoThumbnails objectForKey:@"data"][0];

                [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
                    [FBVideo createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:@{@"id": self.pageID, @"titleDescription": videoInfoToSaveInRealm[@"description"], @"thumbnailsURI": [thumbnailsData valueForKey:@"uri"], @"pageBefore": pageBefore, @"pageAfter": pageAfter}];
                }];

                [self retrieveDataFromRealm];

            }

            //NSLog(@"first product's image: %@", (FBVideo *)[FBVideo allObjects]);

            // Update UICollectionView UI
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                [self.collectionView reloadData];
            });
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)retrieveDataFromRealm {
    RLMResults *objects;

    objects = [FBVideo allObjects];
    FBVideo *fbVideoRealm = [[FBVideo alloc] init];

    for (fbVideoRealm in objects) {
//        NSLog(@"realm object count : %d", (int)objects.count);
        NSLog(@"realm description : %@", fbVideoRealm.titleDescription);
        NSLog(@"realm thumbnails URi : %@", fbVideoRealm.thumbnailsURI);
        NSLog(@"realm page before : %@", fbVideoRealm.pageBefore);
        NSLog(@"realm page after : %@", fbVideoRealm.pageAfter);
    };

}


@end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the Facebook API response directly in Realm (don't display it right away), and then you can follow the pattern demonstrated in [Realm's "TableView" example](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/objc/TableView/TableViewController.m) to back your UITableView with an `RLMResults`, and update the table when its data changes.

Since you'll always be loading data from the Realm this way, you get offline mode "for free".